# Gulp with React not compiling a functional component correctly

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I have the following gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    react = require('gulp-react'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),

    jsxToJs = function() {
      //gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
      gulp.src('./src/sections/header/header.js')
        .pipe(react())
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('javascript.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    };

gulp.task('jsxToJs', jsxToJs);
gulp.task('build', ['jsxToJs', 'styles']);

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch([
        './src/**/*.js', 
        './src/**/*.scss'
    ], [
        'jsxToJs', 
        'styles'
    ]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

And I'm trying to compile the following functional React component:

```
let Header = (props) => {
  return(
    <div />
  );
};
```

However, when I run the javascript.js file created by gulp I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.render is not a function
```

If I convert the component back to the old way of doing things like this (which is how I found it as I'm revisiting an old problem):

```
var Header = React.createClass({
  render: function() {  
  }
});
```

Then it works.

Looking at the compiled JS shows me this - where I can see that `render` is being compiled out correctly with the old syntax, but for the new syntax, while it's being ESfivified it's not being reactified:

```
// not working
"use strict";

var Header = function Header(props) {
  return React.createElement("div", );
};

// working
"use strict";

var Header = React.createClass({ displayName: "Header",
  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement("div", );
  }
});
```

I've checked that I've installed my gulp requires correctly and I'm using Node 6.10.2. My gulp file has some extra things for scss in that I've removed for this question.

A couple of other points:

- I'm not using a bundling tool like browserify as I think it's overkill for this project - so no imports or exports.
- I'm just loading HTML pages that do JSONP to an endpoint and load a script on page that includes the JSON - this is done in a `getInitialState` in the page level HOCs.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be pretty simple.

Babel requires [presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-official-presets) to be provided in order to transpile.

I had the `es2015` preset, but not the [`react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) one. Therefore react specific tranpilations were not occurring. This addition fixed the problem:

```
.pipe(react())
.pipe(babel({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
}))
```

The mistake I was making, that sent me down the wrong rabbit hole in Google, was assuming that failing to reactify was something to do with the gulp-react function - silly me.